# Develop with Docker and WSL 2 in Visual Studio Code - -sh: code: not found

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I follow the tutorial at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/. I have completed the prerequisites steps:

- Install Windows 10, version 2004 or higher.
- Enable WSL 2 feature on Windows. For detailed instructions, refer to the Microsoft documentation.
- Download and install the Linux kernel update package.

[image]

and completed step 1 - `Open VSCode and install the Remote - WSL extension. This extension allows you to work with a remote server in the Linux distro and your IDE client still on Windows.`

[image]

But in step 2, when I run `code .`, it throws an error `-sh: code: not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your path is missing the Visual Studio code path
try, from the linux shell

```
$export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/{username}/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code"
```

this will only work temporarily. The next time you open your shell you will have to do it again.

to make permanent

```
$vi ~/.profile
```

add the line

```
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/{username}/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code"
```

to the end of the file.
then restart you shell and it should be good to go

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_fixing-problems-with-the-code-command-not-working

Comment: Mine is in C drive in window. So it will be `export PATH="C:\Users\findi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\"`?

Comment: you will be running the export function on the linux side. linux mounted your c drive as "/mnt/c/". ``` export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/findi/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code" ```

Comment: Thanks. I can now run `code .` after installing WSL2.

Comment: The path was a bit different for me with WSL2: `export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/host/c/Users/{username}/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"`

Comment: In my case (ubuntu + Oh my ZSH) it was adding:
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/{username}/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"
To created .zshenv file in /mnt/c/Users/{username}

Answer (score -1):

I cannot use the WSL run command to set the PATH variables, so instead
I installed a Linux distribution (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) from the Microsoft store as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#install-your-linux-distribution-of-choice
After that, I booted the distribution, set a username and password, installed vscode by typing "code", navigated to the mnt/... directory and typed "code .".